# nuxt 3 npm generate useCookie before page loaded

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is it possible to load data from cookies before the page starts loading? Or is it impossible when I do npm run generate?
For example:
In header, i use cookies for user email

```
{{profile.email}}
<script setup> import {useCookie} from "nuxt/app"; 
let profile = useCookie('user'); 
</script>
```

When the page loaded profile.email is "" and after 1 sec profile.email is a real email

Or do I want to define lang from cookie
(langCookie is "ru")

```js
    export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {


    function getLang(lang){
        let useCookie1 = useCookie("langCookie"); -->null
        if(useCookie1 && useCookie1.value!=null ){
            if(useCookie1.value === "en" ||  useCookie1.value ==="eng"){
                return "en";
            }else if(useCookie1.value === "ru" || useCookie1.value === "rus"){
                return "ru";
            }else {
                return "en"
            }


        }else { return "en"} --> first

    }
    var a = getLang();

    const i18n = createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        globalInjection: true,
        locale:a,
 
        warnHtmlInMessage: 'off',
        warnHtmlMessage: false,

        messages: {
            en,ru
        }
    })

    vueApp.use(i18n)
    })
```

First the page loads in "en" and after 1sec the page loads in the correct language.K

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use cookies for that?

Comment: @ JTinkers yes, what need to use for PROFILE?

Comment: Cookies are used to keep stuff secure - but that requires `httpOnly`, `secure` and `sameSite` flags to be set. However, when cookie is set to `httpOnly` - you can't use it inside your frontend app. Cookies are meant to be used for stuff like session tokens that can be associated with user upon reqest. They're not for storing user data to use in your frontend - for that, you can use localStorage.

Comment: @JTinkers localStorage will load only in client, i need somethinks for use before will load